# property of a two subset of the space $X=C[0,1]$ with its usual 'sup-norm' topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider the space $X=C[0,1]$ with its usual 'sup-norm' topology.Let

$S$={$f \in X:\int_0^1{f(t)dt \ne 0}$}
$S_1$={$f \in X:\int_0^1{f(t)dt = 0}$}

$1$.Then $S$ is (a) open  , (b) dense in X , (c) connected-which property holds for $S$.
$2$.Then $S_1$ is (a) closed, (b) connected, (c) compact-which property holds for $S_1$.

---

My thoughts:-

for (1) since the map is continuous so $f^{-1}(R-0) $ is open.it is dense but not connected. so a,b are true.
for(2) since S is open so $S_1$ is closed.it is connected.since it is not bounded so not compact. so a,b are true.

Am I right here?

Comment: I would say that you are correct. But if you want you can provide more arguments (for example, why is the map continuous and $S$ not connected?) so that you can help yourself with the understanding of $X$.